# dynamic list creation and naming

Tags: apex, dynamic

Is it possible to create lists dynamically using array notation as below for naming purposes? If so, how do you accomplish it?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I've searched extensively but haven't seemed to be able to find a reference that shows how to do something like this; at least not that I could recognize.

```
for(i=0;i<x,i++){

   list<Event>MyEvent[i] = new list<Event>();

}
```

In essence, I don't know how many lists I'm going to need and want to be able to distinguish between them in a particular use case. They need to be ordered lists, so maps and sets are of no use to me, thus the reason for my question.

I did see a reference to creating an array of Lists or "List of Lists", but received an out of bounds list exception when I attempted to add to `MyList[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using "List of Lists" try the following:

```
if (myList == null)
{
    myList = new List <List <Event>> ();
}

for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (myList.size() == 0)
    {
        myList.add(new List <Event> ());
    }
    else if (myList[i] == null)
    {
        myList.add(i, new List <Event> ());
    }

    // your code
    // myList[i].add(yourEventObject);
}
```

Comment: Made a quick change because there was a question about using `add(index, object)` the other day — a list of size zero chucks an OOB exception if you try to add to 0!

Comment: Clever idea, but I'm getting a list of bounds exception both when Apex executes the `if(myList == null)` statement and when it attempts to add `MyList[i]` to the `list` of `<list<event>>`. Just saw LaceySnr's Comment. My tests would seem to confirm. What change was made, oh, to my post? Gotcha, Thnx!

Comment: Click on "edited XX mins ago" above @LaceySnr's avatar and you should be able to see the change.

Comment: yes, just refreshed. Thnx. Note though that I'm still getting the out of bounds on the if statement, so it appears this would need a "try catch".

Comment: Yeah if you're testing to see if element 3 exists and the list is only 3 items long that will chuck an OOB exception still. Do you really need to use `add(i, object)`? You appear to be running through things sequentially so can you not just use `add(object)`?

Comment: I'm looking at ways to refactor my code to see if I can reuse the same set of lists, so this won't be an issue. Am trying to sort on returns from a query where some opps have multiple activities while most don't. Need to identify those that do so they don't get lost where I make unexpected changes on them. All the code is based on Opp ID. Is a very complex nested query for an after update trigger.

Comment: Are you sure you can't achieve that with a `Map <Id, List <Event>>`?

Comment: @e-bacho That's exactly what I wound up doing. At the end of each loop, I'm putting the lists into maps and clearing them at the start of the next loop. I have related lists for the WhoID's that I also need to keep track of, thus multiple maps with lists for each opp Id.

Comment: Looks like to be the best option in this case...