# Generating a dynamic list in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I looked at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41297/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-list-in-visualforce) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17743/dynamic-list-creation-and-naming) before posting this. I don't understand the responses so much as to tweak them to fit into my needs, so any pointers in the right direction would be great.

So: Say there is a building object that has multiple 'expenses' records (master-detail relationship). Needless to say that the number of expenses per building could vary (electricity, phone, internet, cleaning... etc) Every expense has an escalation rate every year.

What I am trying to do is to generate a report per building like so:
Month Expense1 Expense2 Expense3 ... MonthTotal
1/1/2015 $100 $150 $200 ... SUM
2/1/2015 $100 $150 $200 ... SUM
.
.
.
.
1/1/2016 $100+increase $150+increase $200+increase ... SUM
.
.
.

If there were going to be a finite number of expenses, I know I could just create a data structure and display the report using List. But how do I do this when the number of expenses is varying?

EDIT: How to add a new column for cumulative sum? Like so:

Month Expense1 Expense2 Expense3 ... MonthTotal **CUMULATIVE TOTAL**
1/1/2015 $100 $150 $200 ... sum1 **SUM1**
2/1/2015 $100 $150 $200 ... sum2 **(SUM2 + SUM1)**
.
.
.
.
1/1/2016 $100+increase $150+increase $200+increase ... sumX **(SUMX + SUM(X-1) + SUM(X-2) +... + SUM2 + SUM1)**
.
.
.

Comment: Ok so to boil it down you basically want to create an <apex:pageBlockTable> with a dynamic amount of columns?

Comment: Yes Sir.......!

Comment: I'm having issues accessing my test instance (grr) so this is untested but can you do this? (see answer for formatted code)

Comment: Mind assisting with the controller as well? I am having trouble understanding how the apex:repeat works. Salesforce documentation doesn't do a good job explaining it. I mean, how is this displaying a variable number of columns?

Comment: Yeah sure, i'm on the road atm so I'll have a look when I'm back at my machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DynoListTest" action="{!SetupData}">

    <style type="text/css">
        .empty-column-content {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Wraps}" var="wrap">
            <apex:column value="{!wrap.Name}" headerValue="Header 1" /> <!-- This would be the Opp name or any other Opp fields -->
            <apex:repeat value="{!wrap.exps}" var="exp">
                <apex:column value="{!exp.Amount}" headerValue="This doesn't render" /> <!-- This is the expense name or any other expense field -->
            </apex:repeat>

            <apex:repeat var="header" value="{!headers}">
                <apex:column headerValue="{!header}" styleClass="empty-column-content" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class DynoListTest {

    public List<Wrapper> Wraps {get; set;}
    public List<String> Headers {get; set;}

    public void SetupData() {

        List<Expense> exps = new List<Expense>();
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 1', 100));
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 2', 200));
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 3', 300));

        Wraps = new List<Wrapper>();
        Wraps.add(new Wrapper('Test1', exps));

        exps = new List<Expense>();
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 1', 400));
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 2', 500));
        exps.add(new Expense('Expense 3', 600));

        Wraps.add(new Wrapper('Test2', exps));

        Headers = new List<String>();
        for (Expense exp : exps) {
            Headers.add(exp.Name);
        }
    }

    public class Wrapper {
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public List<Expense> Exps {get; set;}

        public Wrapper(String pName, List<Expense> pExps) {
            Name = pName;
            Exps = pExps;
        }
    }

    public class Expense {
        public String Name {get; set;}
        public Decimal Amount {get; set;}

        public Expense(String pName, Decimal pAmount) {
            Name = pName;
            Amount = pAmount;
        }
    }

}
```

I hit an issue that while pageBlockTables do support the apex:repeat tag with columns inside the column headers don't show up. Fortunately [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245/dynamic-number-of-columns-in-a-pageblocktable) guy has already resolved that by having a separate list of strings that contain the headers. We then render them after the actual columns and hide the cells it produces using CSS.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I now understand how this works! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add to your reputation... can you tell?

Comment: Yeah because you marked it as the best answer I got 25 pts :)

Comment: As an extension to this, how could we calculate the cumulative sum for each expense and display it in new column?

Comment: Do you mean sum up all the expenses per opportunity or do you mean the sum of all "expense 1"? The latter I would expect to be an extra row at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Create a dummy expense record and set its title to "Cumulative Sum" then in the code keep track of the Cumulative Sum and set the expenses Amount field to that.

Comment: I posted a very similar question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66381/display-multiple-liststring-objects-as-columns-in-a-visualforce-page Sorry... but I am unable to extend what you have demonstrated here to achieve the desired layout in my new question. Any help would be great. Thanks.