# Display multiple List<String> objects as columns in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, wrapper-class

I understand that this needs to be done using the infamous wrapper class, but for some reason I am not able to get it to work. Any help would be great.

Goal: Display multiple `List<String>` as columns.

Something like this: 
[image]

I would like to use pageblockTable to accomplish this (or perhaps a pageblockTable within a pageblockTable).

I am storing each column data in a `List<String>` and it does NOT have a fixed number of entries. Each such `List<String>` needs to repeat as columns for as many years as specified by user input.

```
    public class Summary{
            public List<String> summary_list {get; set;}

            public Summary(List<String> s){
                summary_list = s;
            }
        }

        public List<Summary> summary_list_wrap {get; set;}
        public List<String> items_in_column {get; set;}

public void build_Table(){
     //populating the data here - which is working as per the screenshot below
}
```

The values of summary_block_wrap look like this when printed using the below code:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!summary_list_wrap}" var="slw">
                        <apex:column value="{!slw}"/>
                    </apex:pageblockTable>
```

[image]

How do I tweak my visualforce page to match the desired layout?

EDIT: After implementing the answer suggested by Ashwani, the output looks like below. How can we format the table to remove the spacing between the columns and trim the column widths?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a 2 dimensional array or we can say List of List which looks like `List<List<String>> twoDimArray` and try to iterate it like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!twoDimArray}" var="dimension1">
  <apex:pageBlockDataTable value="{!dimension1}" var="dimension2">
    <apex:column value="{!dimension2}"/>
    <!-- etc -->
  </apex:pageBLockDataTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

Here you will have to arrange the collection properly. Possible iteration can be:

```
<apex:repeat value="{! summary_list_wrap}" var="dimension1">
  <apex:pageBlockDataTable value="{!dimension1. summary_list}" var="dimension2">
    <apex:column value="{!dimension2}"/>
    <!-- etc -->
  </apex:pageBLockDataTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

OP ADDED OUTPUT: 
[image]

I would like the output table style to look like that of pageblockTable. But is there a way to get rid of the spacing between the columns? And why is the last column squeezed as opposed to others? I would like to have a 'space trimmed' table instead of something with 100% width and wide spaces in between. How?

Comment: The number of entries in neither dimension 1 nor dimension 2 are static, so repeating apex:column a fixed number of times is not an option.

Comment: If you see there is `<apex:repeat>` which will handle no. of rows. It would be `summary_list_wrap` and `apex:pageBlockDataTable>` will iterate `summary_list` @Kal

Comment: I would like the output table style to look like that of pageblockTable. But is there a way to get rid of the spacing between the columns? And why is the last column squeezed as opposed to others? I would like to have a 'space trimmed' table instead of something with 100% width and wide spaces in between. How?

Comment: You can use css or style attribule on apex column to set the size @kal

Comment: I tried that but no luck. And how to get rid of the spacing in between the columns? That I think has nothing to do with the width of the column itself, right?

Comment: @Kal can you update the post with screenshot?

Comment: Done: updated OP with screenshot.

Comment: @Kal use style attribute on apexpageblocktable instead of apex column and provide padding and margon to 0.

Comment: Thanks, I had to put the columns in a table tag to get what I wanted, but here is something I am stuck with: How do I make the font in JUST the last column to bold? Currently the columns repeat for as many as there are, but how do I program my VF page to apply a specific style to the last column alone?

Comment: apex:pageBlockDataTable is not a valid tag. It should be either apex:pageBlockTable or apex:dataTable.